# Error from fragile beamer-frame within etoolbox's ifbool

Tags: beamer, etoolbox, fragile

Based on `etoolbox` booleans, I am (un)selecting Beamer slides. When I try to do this with a `fragile` frame I run into errors. See MWE.

Could you explain why, and would you have a workaround for this? I would prefer to stay with `etoolbox`'s booleans if possible.

**Minimal working example (MWE)**

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{addcontent}
\booltrue{addcontent}

\begin{document}
  \ifbool{addcontent}{
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
      Fails...
    \end{frame}
  }{}
\end{document}
```

results in the following error:

> File ended while scanning use of \next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a fragile frame is like verbatim and can not be in the argument of another command. use the primitive form `\ifaddcontent .....\fi`  not the form using `{}` arguments

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{addcontent}
\booltrue{addcontent}

\begin{document}
  \ifaddcontent
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
      Fails...
    \end{frame}
 \fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - extremely helpful! Just, `Fails...` may be replaced by `Works...` now ;)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the inverse case or a switch can be realized via `\else`, e.g. `\ifaddcontent\else.......\fi`